# [Spark SQL]: Lookup functionality given two DataFrames and creating a new DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, lookup, apache-spark-1.5

I am using Scala with Spark 1.5.

Given two DataFrames `DataFrame1` and `DataFrame2`, I want to search for values in `DataFrame2` for the keys in `DataFrame1` and create `DataFrame3` with the result. The functionality is unique as `DataFrame1` has many keys in each row and the output DataFrame should have keys and values populated in the same order like shown in the output DataFrame below. I'm looking for a distributed solution, if possible, as this functionality should to be implemented on millions of records (~10 million records). Any directions on how to proceed and information on useful methods is of great help. Thanks in advance!

**Input: DataFrame1 (contract_id along with maximum of 4    customers associated)**

```
contract_id, cust1_id, cust2_id, cust3_id, cust4_id
500001,100000001,100000002,100000003,100000004
500305,100000001,100000002,100000007
500303,100000021
500702,110000045
500304,100000021,100000051,120000051
503001,540000012,510000012,500000002,510000002
503051,880000045
```

**Input: DataFrame2 (Customer master lookup information)**

```
cust_id,date_of_birth
100000001,1988-11-04
100000002,1955-11-16
100000003,1980-04-14
100000004,1980-09-26
100000007,1942-03-07
100000021,1964-06-22
100000051,1920-03-12
120000051,1973-11-17
110000045,1955-11-16
880000045,1980-04-14
540000012,1980-09-26
510000012,1973-03-15
500000002,1958-08-18
510000002,1942-03-07
```

#### **Output: DataFrame3**

```
contract_id, cust1_id, cust2_id, cust3_id, cust4_id, cust1_dob, cust2_dob, cust3_dob, cust4_dob 
500001,100000001,100000002,100000003,100000004,1988-11-04,1955-11-16,1980-04-14,1980-09-26
500305,100000001,100000002,100000007,         ,1988-11-04,1955-11-16,1942-03-07
500303,100000021,         ,         ,         ,1964-06-22
500702,110000045          ,         ,         ,1955-11-16
500304,100000021,100000051,120000051,         ,1964-06-22,1920-03-12,1973-11-17
503001,540000012,510000012,500000002,510000002,1980-09-26,1973-03-15,1958-08-18,1942-03-07
503051,880000045          ,         ,         ,1980-04-14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most effective solution but this works for your case.

```
  import spark.implicits._

  val df1 = spark.sparkContext
    .parallelize(
      Seq(
        ("500001", "100000001", "100000002", "100000003", "100000004"),
        ("500305", "100000001", "100000002", "100000007", ""),
        ("500303", "100000021", "", "", ""),
        ("500702", "110000045", "", "", ""),
        ("500304", "100000021", "100000051", "120000051", ""),
        ("503001", "540000012", "510000012", "500000002", "510000002"),
        ("503051", "880000045", "", "", "")
      ))
    .toDF("contract_id", "cust1_id", "cust2_id", "cust3_id", "cust4_id")

  val df2 = spark.sparkContext
    .parallelize(
      Seq(
        ("100000001", "1988-11-04"),
        ("100000002", "1955-11-16"),
        ("100000003", "1980-04-14"),
        ("100000004", "1980-09-26"),
        ("100000007", "1942-03-07"),
        ("100000021", "1964-06-22"),
        ("100000051", "1920-03-12"),
        ("120000051", "1973-11-17"),
        ("110000045", "1955-11-16"),
        ("880000045", "1980-04-14"),
        ("540000012", "1980-09-26"),
        ("510000012", "1973-03-15"),
        ("500000002", "1958-08-18"),
        ("510000002", "1942-03-07")
      ))
    .toDF("cust_id", "date_of_birth")

  val finalDF = df1
    .join(df2, df1("cust1_id") === df2("cust_id"), "left")
    .drop("cust_id")
    .withColumnRenamed("date_of_birth", " cust1_dob")
    .join(df2, df1("cust2_id") === df2("cust_id"), "left")
    .drop("cust_id")
    .withColumnRenamed("date_of_birth", " cust2_dob")
    .join(df2, df1("cust3_id") === df2("cust_id"), "left")
    .drop("cust_id")
    .withColumnRenamed("date_of_birth", " cust3_dob")
    .join(df2, df1("cust4_id") === df2("cust_id"), "left")
    .drop("cust_id")
    .withColumnRenamed("date_of_birth", " cust4_dob")

  finalDF.na.fill("").show()
```